# Titanium Build Error Invalid Device

Tags: android, titanium

I've recently updated my Android SDK to the latest available and I'm getting the following error when I try to build from the command line and deploy to my Samsung Galaxy S3:

> $ titanium build -p android -T device -C --device-id 6f01b9ae
>
> Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.4.0, Titanium SDK version 3.4.0.GA
>
> Copyright (c) 2012-2014, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
>
> Please report bugs to http://jira.appcelerator.org/
>
> [ERROR] :  Invalid "--device-id" value "6f01b9ae"
>
> For help, run: titanium help build

Does anybody have anything I can try to get past this? I'm pretty stuck and would really appreciate some help.
Thanks!

Comment: I've tried restarting titanium, unplugging my phone, and restarting the MAC on which I'm developing.

Answer (score 1):

Because the Titanium tooling uses android's adb to push to your device, first run

```
adb devices
```

Verify that the device is seen by adb and that the id you are using matches.

Second, -C and --device-id are the same flags and do not need to be repeated. These are the same:

```
$ titanium build -p android -T device -C 6f01b9ae
$ titanium build -p android -T device --device-id 6f01b9ae
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question! It seems like something is really wrong, however. When I run 'adb devices', I see my phone in the list but the result of trying to build remains the same. Do you have any suggestions as to what might be causing this? Many thanks!

Comment: $ ./adb devices
List of devices attached 
6f01b9ae unauthorized